# this given code should convert a given number into lagest possible no.by replacing suitable no of digits by 9.It is not working

Tags: c++

`x` and `k` are number to be converted and digits to be replaced respectively.
The function `int dig` counts the number of digits of the number.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int dig(long int n)
{
    int m=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        n=n/10;
        m++;
    }
    return m;   
}

int main(void){
   long long int x,f=1;//here x should take an input upto 18 digits.
   int b=1,k,l,c,j=1,i,r;
   cin>>x;
   cin>>k;
   l=dig(x);
   c=l-k;
   for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
   {
      f=f*10;
   } 
   r=(x%f);
   for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
   {
      b=b*10;
   }    
   j=(b-1)*f;
   j=j+r;
   cout<<j;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `dig(0)`?

Comment: The function `int dig(long int n)` works, it returns the number of digits. So `dig(0) will return 1`. I tested the code and I'am not sure what you want to do. Could you please provide more informations, maybe with an example what exactly you want to do. Answering would be easier then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the code, it looks like your intention is to replace the first k digits of the (up to 18 digit number) x with 9's, and thereby get the resulting large number? i.e. inputting 12345678 and 4 should give 99995678?

If so, read on. If not, disregard this answer.

The logic in the code is correct but it won't handle 18 digits due to loss of precision; some of your variables need to be changed to long long integers to support 18 digits. Note the compiler warnings.

Also, the code does not seem to handle negative values of x correctly, but that is easy to fix (see the use of mul). And it doesn't protect against k being too large, but that is also an easy fix.

Here's a corrected version: with this inputting 123456789012345678 and 4 gives 999956789012345678. Hope this helps.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int dig(long long int n)
{
    int m = 0;
    while (n>0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        m++;
    }
    return m;
}

int main(void) {
    long long int x, f = 1;//here x should take an input upto 18 digits.
    int b = 1, k, l, c;
    long long int j = 1;
    int i;
    long long int r;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> k;
    int mul = (x < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    x *= mul;
    l = dig(x);
    if (k > l)
    {
        k = l;
    }
    c = l - k;
    for (i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    {
        f = f * 10;
    }
    r = (x%f);
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        b = b * 10;
    }
    j = (b - 1)*f;
    j = j + r;
    j *= mul;
    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot .It was really helpful!!